# сгенеририровать список смежности для графа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы, геометрия

есть `n` точек на плоскости, которые задаются произвольным порядком, известно, что любые две точки соединяются отрезком (тоесть являются смежными вершинами в терминах графов либо могут быть соединены какой то промежуточной точкой/точками лежашей на этой прямой)

пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует по какому алгоритму можно получить следующий список смежности ?

```
0 -> 1 2 3
1 -> 3
2 -> 3
3 -> пустое множество
```

Тоесть необходимо для каждой вершины найти все его смежные вершины (точки), причём так, чтобы одно и тоже ребро два раза не определялось для смежных вершин - (именно поэтому для 3 ей вершины пустое множество так как до этого все ребра уже определились)

Пускай в коде этот список будет представлен, например так

`std::vector<std::list<int>> adj(N);`

какие есть идеи ?

Comment: Так как в условии *"любые две точки соединяются отрезком"*, то у вас не хватает ребра `1->2`. Они тоже соединяются отрезком...

Comment: @Harry в условии ещё говорится что две точки могут быть соединены промежуточными точками лежащими на одной прямой

Comment: Это называется "связный граф".

Comment: Ну тогда нужно просто проверять для всех ребер, не лежит ли какая вершина на этом ребре. Конечно, непосредственный алгоритм дает O(N^3), если не ошибаюсь. Конечно, есть эвристики, которые могут ускорить процесс; вероятно, есть и более быстрый алгоритм какого-нибудь выметания :), но тут я пас. А O(N^3) - в принципе, реализуется несложно.

Answer (score 4):

Из вашего описания не очень понятно, какие именно вершины надо найти. Нельзя просто для каждой вершины перечислить все смежные, у которых больше номер по-порядку? Этим мы гарантируем, что все ребра будут перечислены, и никакое не встретится 2 раза.

Comment: главный критерий это чтобы ни одно ребро два раза не встретилось

Comment: непонятно что имеется ввиду под "больше номер по порядку" ? как это обеспечит уникальность ребёр ?

Comment: @ampawd Ребро `(i,j)` при `i<j` попадает в список только как `(i,j)`, но не как `(j,i)`.

Comment: `главный критерий это чтобы ни одно ребро два раза не встретилось` - тогда алгоритм плоский как блин: для очередной вершины вывести все рёбра, выходящие из этой вершины и не выведенные раньше. Простейшая реализация - сортируем рёбра по минимальному из номеров вершин и выводим в порядке возрастания номеров вершин прямо по списку.

Comment: Не могли бы вы на примере графа вмвопросе продемонстрировать ваш подход?

Comment: @Akina мне не понятно как в реализации обеспечить факт "не выведенных ранее" - и ещё не могли бы вы показать пример работы этого алгоритма на входных данных из вопроса ?

Comment: @ampawd, результат работы этого алгоритма полностью совпадает с результататом из вашего вопроса. Насчет невозможности повтора выше написал Harry. Еще раз: для вершины i мы берем только такие ребра (i, j), для которых i < j. Предположим, что ребро (a, b) попало в два списка одновременно. Это будет означать, что a < b и b < a, что невозможно.